# Selenium Python select the link from 3rd column from a table

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a page with a table with some rows and columns. The first column has a checkbox (index is 0). The 2nd column has the name. The 3rd column has a link called view.  There are some rows of data in the table. 
I would like to click the view link which has the name "Selenium_CRM_For_Edit_Test"
The name could be anywhere in the table of rows.

I can identify the column name with the following XPATH:

```
//span[contains(., "Selenium_CRM_Edit_Test")]
```

I do not know how to get to the next column which has the view link

I have tried the following XPath:

```
//span[contains(., "Selenium_CRM_Edit_Test")]/../preceding-sibling::td/div/span[contains(text(), "view")]
```

That does not work.  I thought preceding-sibling would go down to the next TD element

The HTML snippet is:

```
<table id="data_configuration_data_previews_ct_fields_body" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
<colgroup>
<tbody>
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBFG GJPPK2LBMG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="18">
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBHG GJPPK2LBNG">
        <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBNG">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-237" style="outline-style:none;">
                <span class="linkhover" title="Selenium_LADEMO_CRM_DONOTCHANGE" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">Selenium_CRM_For_Edit_Test</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBNG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-238" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="linkhover" title="view" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">view</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBNG">
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBBH GJPPK2LBNG">
    </tr>
<tr class="GJPPK2LBEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="19">
<tr class="GJPPK2LBFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="20">
</tbody>
```

How do i get to the link which has the name Selenium_CRM_For_Edit_Test?

Thanks,
Riaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to locate the

```
<span class="linkhover" title="view" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">view</span>
```

element, based on the text in

```
<span class="linkhover" title="Selenium_LADEMO_CRM_DONOTCHANGE" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">Selenium_CRM_For_Edit_Test</span>
```

you can use the `following` axis:

```
//span[contains(., "Selenium_CRM_Edit_Test")]/following::span[@class="linkhover"]
```

Comment: I managed to use this Xpath to get the view link: 
//span[@title = 'Selenium_CRM_Edit_Test']/ancestor::tr[1]/td[3]//span[contains(text(), "view")]

Comment: Your one will be better.  I will use that.  Thanks